# Default Gravatar on wildcard email addresses unless specified

Tags: gravatar

I own my domain and I use different email addresses for different sites, depending on what the site does, whether I think they'll spam me, etc.

Is there a way to tell Gravatar to use a picture for *@example.com unless it's already been defined?

I realize the wildcard would need verification. Gravatar could use the contact information for the domain as a way to validate the request.

Comment: Please give it a whirl and answer your own question. :)

Comment: I tried, but couldn't make it work. I was hoping there was some way I hadn't thought of. David Schwartz' comment points out a good reason.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's impossible. Gravatar doesn't actually operate on email addresses but [MD5 hashes of them](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/). There's no way to relate email addresses that have the same portion after the `@` sign. If you send Gravatar an email that's not specifically in its database, it has no way to even tell what domain you are asking about.

This is by design to ensure we all know Gravatar isn't collecting email addresses. Otherwise, people would be reluctant to check for a Gravatar -- if the person didn't have one, you'd be giving Gravatar their email address.

Comment: Cool, great answer!

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but quality nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: So I guess for domain-level avatars to work, it's needed to change the API (or docs on best practices how to use the API) so that website developers should first try to get avatar with hash of email, and if it fails, with hash of email's domain?

Comment: I don't see why they couldn't just have a hashed '@domain.com', and if the address requested doesn't have an explicit email address, just use the fallback.

Comment: @DanAtkinson If you can try to guess the domain and full email address separately, many email addresses become guessable. Consider an email like mine -- `donald@ripple.com`. I doubt you'd get that by brute force. But if you pre-hashed the top few million domains, you'd get the `ripple.com` part. Then if you tried common first names and last names in combination, you'd get the whole thing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But the hash of the domain doesn't need to be externally visible as the request is only for the hashed email address. It's just that the server would fall back to the domain gravatar instead.

Comment: @DanAtkinson How would the sender get the domain gravatar if they didn't send the hash of the domain?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not sure I understand. Website first sends f6efaf653ca6e67438510cb186250c2c (donald@ripple.com) to gravatar and gets back a 404 or whatever. Then website sends 956b901ef936876db7ba82cebb2cfeb7 (@ripple.com) to gravatar. Gravatar has a match for the domain so sends back the avatar that was set up. How does this expose an email address to them?

Comment: @Gerry They can now brute force the two halves individually. They can trivially hash the top one million domains to find `ripple.com`. Then they can trivially hash the top ten thousand names (with `@ripple.com` added to them) to get the `donald` part. If they had to get both at once, it would be much harder.

Comment: This is a bit crazy. If this was really the threat, they could already do this for gmail, hotmail and yahoo to get the vast majority of emails. Also your top million domains crossed with top 10K names is only 10 billion hashes, which can be searched very quickly. Sending the domain first doesn't really help. md5online.org can already search 123 billion hashes.

If somebody really wants to reverse most of the emails, they already can.

Comment: @Gerry That would require some sort of a scripted pre-test, either server or client side. Gravatar doesn't work that way. In fact, it's very simple: Sites put the hashed value in an `img src`, Gravatar sends back an image, and that's it.